# Material is not showing in solid mode?

Tags: materials, 3d-view

I was trying to apply a material to the object but it does not show up in **Solid mode** when I switch to **Material mode** the color shows up.

**Solid Mode:**
[image: Solid Mode]

**Material Mode:** 
[image: Material Mode]

Comment: If you wish to use cycles materials on your object, you can't expect to see them in the viewport, except in "rendered" mode (next major version 2.8 will likely hugely improve this).

Answer (score 2):

Scroll to the very bottom of the Materials panel, go to Settings and use the Viewport Color. ;)

Comment: Also make sure you do that for each individual material you wish to see :)

Comment: but keep in mind that viewport color is not the one rendered by cycles... it just helps fir a fast viewport look.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue, its the default behavior of the blender, if you want to see the materials in solid mode you may use the material tab to drag and drop same color on the **Viewport color** just under the settings. As shown below:

**Drag and Drop:**

[image]

**Result:**
[image]